# App working in when your in the lock screen Xcode 6

Tags: swift, lockscreen

I am making a stopwatch app that is saying when your timer is finished. The app makes a sound when the timer is finished. The problem is that if the user puts the timer on 15 minutes and the phone goes to the lock screen after 5 the app doesn't work. Is there a way to get it work though it is in lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. There are a few cases where Apple allows your app's code to continue to run from the background, but a timer app is not one of those. Do a search on `UIBackgroundModes` in the Xcode docs to see a list of the background services Apple supports.

Local notifications (`UILocalNotification`) are probably the closest thing to what you want. You can submit a local notification with a specific "fire date" that will either send a message to your app if it is currently running, or display a notification to the user if it's in the background. When the user taps your notification your app gets brought to the foreground (or launched if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

No, due to restrictions. This might help:- 
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/